# Create new Excel file that includes current foler name in Excel vbscript

Tags: excel, file, vbscript

I am new to vbscript, but wanted to know how to automatically create a new excel file in a folder that has the format "[folder name]_Summary.xlsx?  I am getting a file to be created, but I had to hard code the path.  Is there a way to automatically create the new excel file in the folder?

Here is what I have thus far:

```
Sub Testing()

strFileName = "F:\U029\U029_Excel\U029_Excel_Summary.xlsx"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
objWorkbook.SaveAs (strFileName)

objExcel.Quit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your vbs file is placed inside the folder in which you want to create excel file. After running the vbs file, you can delete it from that folder. Use this code inside the vbs file:

```
call fn_createExcel()

Function fn_CreateExcel()
    Dim objFso, objExcel, objWorkbook
    Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemobject")
    strTemp = objFso.GetAbsolutePathName("")
    tempArr=Split(strTemp,"\")
    strFileName= strTemp&"\"&tempArr(ubound(tempArr))&"_Summary.xlsx"
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objExcel.Visible = True
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
    objWorkbook.SaveAs strFileName

    objExcel.Quit
    Set objExcel = Nothing
    Set objFso = Nothing
End Function
```

EDIT 2:
Create a xlsm file having the vba code as below(also see the image attached). Place this xlsm file inside the folder where you want the excel files to be created, open and run the procedure. After excel file is created, you can remove this xlsm file from that folder.

```
Function fn_CreateExcel()
    Dim objExcel, objWorkbook, strFileName, strTemp
    strTemp = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    tempArr = Split(strTemp, "\")
    strFileName = strTemp & "\" & tempArr(UBound(tempArr)) & "_Summary.xlsx"
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objExcel.Visible = True
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
    objWorkbook.SaveAs strFileName

    objExcel.Quit
    Set objExcel = Nothing
End Function
```

You can modify the code/logic further as per your requirement. I have tried this code and is working.[image]

Comment: thanks for your solution.  How do I go about having this code work in a VBA excel sheet?  I pasted your code into the VBA project in excel but got the error "Invalid outside procedure".  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try for this vbscript :

```
Call Create_New_Excel_File()
'***********************************************************
Sub Create_New_Excel_File()
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Path_Folder = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
Array_Folder_Name = split(Path_Folder,"\")
Folder_Name = Array_Folder_Name(Ubound(Array_Folder_Name))
strFileName = Path_Folder & "\" & Folder_Name & "_Summary.xlsx"
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
objWorkbook.SaveAs(strFileName)
objExcel.Quit
End Sub
'***********************************************************
```

Comment: I get a compile error," Invalid outside procedure ".

Comment: @Joe This works with vbscript not with VBA
I have tested it before posting it and it works with vbscript !